# Do arrays of "non-zero" primitives require more memory?

Tags: java, memory, primitive

Hi all when writing an array list implementation, I understand it is important to set `Item(x)` to null when it is removed (instead of simply `quantity -= 1`) so as to prevent memory leaks.

However, if my array list is a primitive int array list (backed by a `int[]`), does it make sense to set it to 0?

Similary, for an array list of primitive chars (backed by a `char[]`), when RemoveRange() is called, does it make sense to fill that range with `\u0000`? Or is it totally fine simply to update the `length` and pointers without modifying the backing array?

Is an array of ints filled with zeros *possibly* less memory-occupying than an equal length array filled with integer values because the runtime could make **optimizations** ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the answer to this one's a bit illogical. I'll let someone smarter to do the explanation just because my memory is too hazy on the subject.

Comment: It is very tempting to falsely confirm that an int[] gets the bigger the greater numbers one holds. Do some people have no model of how a computer works at all?

Comment: @Ingo I was thinking optimizations could be made if they were all the same value (i.e. 0)

Comment: @Pacerier actually, in most linux kernels, `calloc` does optimize that, as it has a page separate from all others that is always set to 0. When you attempt to write to it the first time, it then changes the page you are trying to write to to a newly wiped page in memory, to save on those precious resources. However, I do not think that anything like this is available in java.

Comment: It's theoretically possible, and I vaguely recall some systems that attempted this sort of thing.  (Certainly APL does it, but it's dynamically typed.)  But I don't think any production Java or C-like system does it (other than stuff like the storage swizzle mentioned by Richard).

Comment: (And it should be noted that one should avoid making unnecessary changes to storage (such as zeroing unused space), since this "dirties" the cache unnecessarily, and cache management is about 50% of Java performance optimization.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is an array of ints filled with zeros possibly less memory-occupying than an equal length array filled with integer values?

Assuming in both cases we're dealing with an `int[]` - no. Two arrays of the same type and the same length will always occupy the same amount of memory.

There's no *need* to overwrite your "now empty" array elements with 0. It wouldn't do any harm (beyond a tiny performance benefit), and may even make things simpler when debugging, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

> ... when writing an array list implementation, I understand it is important to set `Item(x)` to `null` when it is removed (instead of simply `quantity -= 1`) so as to prevent memory leaks.

This isn't true. Setting variables to `null` is not something that is always necessary and not doing so does not mean that you have a memory leak.

> However, if my array list is a primitive int array list, does it make sense to set it to 0?

No, for primitives it doesn't matter at all, 0 or `\u0000` (for a char) is just a value like any other value. It doesn't take up less space.

Comment: It *is* necessary if you're implementing an `ArrayList`-like type though. If I add an item and then remove that element from the list, I don't want that reference to be hanging around in the list for no reason.

Comment: If you're managing your own memory then you have to manage nullifying objects not used. If not then the GC picks it up if there are no further refs to that object (at some unspecified time).

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it's probably a good idea if you're implementing your own `List`. Many people though think that setting variables to `null` in general is a good idea (without understanding exactly why). In my opinion, you shouldn't do things just because you have a vague idea that it is "good" - only do it if you understand why.

Comment: @Jesper: True - but in this case the question does *state* the context.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not necessary to do so with primitive types (i.e. set them to 0) since the only reason "slots" are explicitly nulled out are to prevent fake references to them thereby screwing around with garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an `ArrayList<int>` nor any other container class with primitives. Regarding plain arrays, see Jon Skeets answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows that and wants to create his own non-generic `ArrayList` class like `IntArrayList`.

Comment: +Sanjay - I am not so sure. Anyway, I am not supposed to answer what someone could have possibly meant, but to answer what he did ask.

Comment: I read it as he's implementing his own array list (not using ArrayList).

Comment: @wmorrison365 yes you are right I'm taling about an array list of primitive ints not a java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Primitives and references always occupy the same amount of space.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to nullify the object slot in the array to prevent the leak. If the object is still referenced by your array then it can't be GC'd - so the leak you refer to.

Primitives on the other hand are allocated on the stack anyway, not the heap, so aren't GC'd anyway. Primitives that are instance vars of classes are stored as fields of the relevant object and cleaned up when the object is GC'd.

Additionally, the JLS indicates that the size of a primitive is VM-specific but most (all?) VMs currently support 4byte ints. See the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2) for more info: